# Replace a item in string array

Tags: c#, linq, string

I have a string array and want to replace a value from that array.

Example:

```
string[] stud = new[] {"1","12","Mark","M"};
string[] otherStud = new [] {"2","16","MarkMark","F"};
```

I want to replace the `Mark` with `Tom`, then Result should be

Result:

```
string[] stud = new [] {"1","12","Tom","M"};
string[] otherStud = new [] {"2","16","TomTom","F"};
```

please suggest any solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
stud = stud.Select( s => s.Replace("Mark","Tom") ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] stud = { "1", "12", "Mark", "M", "2", "16", "MarkMark", "F" };
for (int i = 0; i < stud.Length; ++i)
     stud[i] = stud[i].Replace("Mark", "Tom");
```

Comment: The second result will return as "Tom" but i want it as "TomTom"

Comment: If only you had run it, you would have seen that it returns "TomTom" :)

Comment: I had run it...& it gives me only Tom

Comment: It returns "TomTom" for me... Are you sure you copy paste my code exactly as is?

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] stud = {"1", "12", "Mark", "M"};
        for (int i = 0; i < stud.Count(); i++)
        {
            stud[i] = stud[i].Replace("Mark", "Tom");
        }
```

Comment: But for "MarkMark" it should retun "TomTom"

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` and in loop use `String.Replace`. You should be able to figure out how it should look exacly. :)

Comment: I have done that but i am having problem in replacing "MarkMark" with "TomTom"

Comment: `Replace` works on all instances of old string so if u use it like this: `"MarkMark".Replace("Mark", "Tom")` then ull get `"TomTom"`. Btw remember that Replace doesn't change string it returns new one.

Answer (score 0):

you can traverse the string array using foreach and can replace the required string

Answer (score -2):

`stud.Select(x => x != "Mark" ? x : "Tom");`

Comment: That won't work on "MarkMark" to "TomTom"

Comment: @Chony, you're over-complicating your solution.